# Should "each" be followed by a singular or plural possessive?

Tags: punctuation, british-english, possessives, apostrophe

If a possessive noun, which is plural, is preceded by "each", then should it use the singular or plural possessive form?

For example, which of the following is correct?

- spend time in each other's presence
- spend time in each others' presence

Comment: If this is not to be something more than off-topic proofreading, you should expand upon your research, your thinking, and your question.

Comment: There are apparently 650,000 instances of [in each others'](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22in+each+others'%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) in Google Books, so if this really is General Reference, that's still a lot of **published writers** getting it wrong. For that reason alone, I'm not going to closevote.

Comment: I have voted to close this question. It is based on a false premise and has led to an off-topic debate about a specific example.  Note: The false premise is that a plural noun can be preceded by 'each'. It can't because 'each' is always singular. This is independent of whether there is a possessive. The false premise is stated implicitly but glossed over in the first clause of the first sentence.

Comment: @chaslyfromUK: where is the off-topic debate? The top-voted answer says the same thing you do in your answer, just shorter. Another answer, although it has clearly been controversial, gives an example of why some people might use *each others'*. The third answer is just wrong, yes. That's hardly a lot of answers.

Comment: @sumelic - That is a fair comment. I should not blame the OP for the ensuing debate. Instead I should, and do, blame the OP for sneaking in a controversial assumption in the first sentence. The assumption is that you could say for example, "each men" or "each rabbits" or "each oases" or use 'each' with any other plural noun.  This assumption invalidates the rest of the question. I'd give dictionary and grammar support for my view that 'each' cannot be followed by a plural but then that would become an off-topic answer to a question that I don't accept in the first place.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Each other* is singular, so the correct possessive is *each other's*.

Edit: 
I found some controversy on this on the web because *each other* implies that there are multiple people involved, hence people think it is plural and should be written *each others'*. This, however, is wrong as *each* is always singular.

Comment: Controvery may exist, but it is misled and misleading, because quite simply *each* takes a singular, ***always.***  You do not and cannot say *each *men*; you only and always say *each man*.  That shows why *each others'* is necessarily wrong.

Comment: @sumelic but **each other's presence** is exactly something I'd say. Why wouldn't you?

Answer (score 0):

You may find that style guides say that it must be *other's*, but both can be defended, *other’s* because *presence* is singular, *others’* because there is a degree of mutuality in the state described. As Pam Peters put it in ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’, ‘the formal grammar of words and the notional grammar of the underlying semantics are at loggerheads.’

If you’re feeling adventurous, you can omit the apostrophe altogether.

Comment: Hmm. There's a fine line between being adventurous and being mistaken. Like jumping over a wall to find a forty-foot drop on the other side.

Comment: When do you use *each* with a plural noun? Never.  It must be *each man*, never *each *men*. That puts to bed any possibility of *each *others'*.

Comment: @tchrist. Pam Peters (see my answer) considers the sentence _The group read each other’s / others’ letters_. She comments ‘there are multiple participants “in the group” . . . _other’s_ seems a little awkward when the noun following is plural (_letters_) and the wording implies more than a single exchange.’ But remove the apostrophe altogether and any problem disappears.

Comment: Are you /is she advocating the total abandoning of apostrophes to mark possessives? I couldn't agree with that as an improvement - but I'm by no means against change per se. When I see things like 'this **is** the rule' with a supporting _authoritative_ quote, I usually start looking feverishly for a different _authority_ I can quote which says the rule doesn't hold universally.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. There has been confusion over its use since it was introduced in the mid-sixteenth century. Features of language that serve no purpose tend to disappear over time, and this is already happening in cases like _parents evening_. I don’t mind trying to encourage its demise from time to time, but these things can’t be rushed.

Comment: Yes - we have both a dogs home and a dogs' home (capitalised as parts of proper nouns, of course) within 15 miles of here. I do, however, think that the possessive (rather than the attributive) usage is valuable, as it avoids certain ambiguities - I'll post one (if I can think of one), if you like. Ah yes - dog's home (where Fido lives), dogs' home (where Prince & Rex live) and dogs home (where they board strays etc).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth So does that mean that those are the home of a dog; the home of a couple of dogs; and a home **for** dogs? I'm still not sure that's entirely justified though, because it validates *parents evening*, which is simply **wrong**.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth. The John Lewis restaurant in Reading has a sign over the counter for younger eaters that proclaims _Childrens_. Kingsley Amis gave the example _Those things are my husband’s_ compared with _Those things are my husbands_. In practice, context, will remove most ambiguity. There are no apostrophes in speech.

Comment: @Andrew Leach _Parents evening_ has always been justifiable on the ground that _parents_ is attributive.

Comment: @Barrie If you say so, but I don't believe it **is** attributive. Can you give an example where *parents* is unassailably attributive and **cannot** be possessive? I might be persuaded.

Comment: @AndrewLeach: Even in that example, the parents don't 'possess' the evening, but an example which shows attributive use perhaps even more clearly is _teachers college_.

Comment: I record some further interesting examples here: http://realgrammar.posterous.com/apostrophes. See also the EL&U blog: http://english.blogoverflow.com/2012/11/much-ado-about-possessive-apostrophes/

Comment: @AndrewLeach: There are articles on (1) unpredictable apostrophe usage in proper nouns at http://articles.courant.com/2003-01-15/features/0301150773_1_diners-club-diners-club-veterans-day and (2) recommended apostrophe usage with 'nonpossessive and generic phrases' at  http://dict.leo.org/forum/viewGeneraldiscussion.php?idThread=475863&lp=ende&lang=de . A travellers cheque may not belong to a traveller. A mens clothing department contains clothing that may be designed for men but will still belong to the company (and notice the disturbing new word required, _mens_).

Answer (score -2):

Surely it's always *each others* 
**Each other** is a (reciprocal) pronoun, so in its possessive case it becomes a possessive pronoun. 
None of the others: its, his, hers, yours, whose etc has an apostrophe. Adding one is generally seen as a sign of poor literacy.

Comment: This answer is based on a false rule: not all pronouns lack an apostrophe in the possessive form. For example, this is not true for indefinite pronouns like "one's, someone's, somebody's."